# How to change data description in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have build a database and by creating a table I forgot to do at the id the option auto_increment by extra's.

How can I implement this data-description in the existing database? I use MYSQL 5.6 Command Line Client (windows).

Comment: Can you not modify the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ALTER TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35ae8/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE xxx CHANGE id id  INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ALLITEMS(
    itemid INT(10)UNSIGNED,
    itemname VARCHAR(50)
);

ALTER TABLE ALLITEMS CHANGE itemid itemid INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

DESC ALLITEMS;

INSERT INTO ALLITEMS(itemname)
VALUES
    ('Apple'),
    ('Orange'),
    ('Banana');

SELECT * FROM ALLITEMS;
```

I was confused with `CHANGE` and `MODIFY` keywords before too:

```
ALTER TABLE ALLITEMS CHANGE itemid itemid INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE ALLITEMS MODIFY itemid INT(5);
```

While we are there, also note that `AUTO_INCREMENT` can also start with a predefined number:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE TABLE ALLITEMS( 
itemid INT(10)UNSIGNED,
 itemname VARCHAR(50)
 );

ALTER TABLE ALLITEMS CHANGE itemid itemid INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT;